# what does this kinds of if mean?

Tags: latex

I saw a config file on:
https://github.com/tzengyuxio/pages/blob/gh-pages/pandoc/pm-template.latex

In this file, there is some kinds of "if" that make me confused.

- $if(fontsize)$$fontsize$,$endif$   % In my mind $xxx$ means a mathematical formula, but why does it appear in if-else statement?
- \ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0   % What does this means? Does the 0, 1, 1 mean argument for commands ifnum, ifxetex and ifluatex? Shouldn't the arguments be in braces "{}" ? And what does it mean together?
- And there is another kind of if: \IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{} % Why does this command have so many braces?

Why is there so many kinds of if? What is the differences of them?